# Tell DataGridView that custom paint does not fit inside cell

Tags: winforms, datagridview, cell, customization, paint

I paint the content of a cell for example an icon and text. If the text does not fit the cell bounds it is drawed with ellipsis. How can I tell the `DataGridView` that the cell needs more space to handle autosizing correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various options presented in [Customizing Content-based Sizing Behavior](Customizing Content-based Sizing Behavior); I recommend that you override the [DataGridViewCell.GetPreferredSize Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.getpreferredsize) to provide custom cell size data to the specific DataGridViewColumn's [CellTemplate Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.celltemplate?view=netframework-4.8).

Since you have not detailed your particular design conditions, I will assume that the the DataGridViewColumn is a [DataGridViewTextBoxColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewtextboxcolumn?view=netframework-4.8).

The custom cell definition would be something similar to the following.

```VB
Public Class CustomSizedTextBoxCell : Inherits DataGridViewTextBoxCell

  Protected Overrides Function GetPreferredSize(graphics As Graphics, cellStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle, rowIndex As Int32, constraintSize As Size) As Size
    Dim ret As Size = MyBase.GetPreferredSize(graphics, cellStyle, rowIndex, constraintSize)
    ' this simple example just doubles the width of the base preferred size
    ' replace this with logic that satifies your requirements
    ret.Width *= 2
    Return ret
  End Function

End Class
```

The to use this custom cell:

```
DataGridView1.Columns(0).CellTemplate = New CustomSizedTextBoxCell()
```